# Is there anything constant is every conceivable world/situation?

Tags: metaphysics, possible-worlds

Is there anything constant, in every world, video game, universe, location, time, dream, the Real world, etc.? I know about logical constants, but those are just fixed definitions of terms, they are constant because of convention. Is there anything that is constant or the same in the real world, in imaginary worlds, in this universe, in other possible universes, in logical worlds, in illogical worlds, in all types of video games, during now, in the past, in the future, in dreams, in books, in tv shows, in movies, etc.? Basically, I am trying to give some kind of order to my life, as any time there is a thing there is an alternative, i.e. if you have a cup, there could be no cup, if there is something real, there could be something imaginary, if there is something in one game/tv show/movie, there it might not be in another. Basically, Is there something you could rely/depend on, even if (please assume the following is possible, just for the sake of the question) you got thrown into an alternate universe, or put into a tv show or movie, or got transferred into a video game, or got thrown back in time, or thrown into the future, or put in the bottom of the ocean, etc.

### Basically,

what can you rely on/depend on in any and all imaginable situations?

Note that by rely/depend on I mean something which just is, not necessarily something that allows you to cope or survive or whatever, but rather something that can give a sense or order. It is really hard for me, as I like order, but I cannot find an overall order in everything imaginable.

Comment: According to the famous 2nd law of thermodynamics in classical physics the universe or any closed physical system tend towards maximal *orderless*, then why do you like *order* in an anti-natural law way? And do you *really* like the supposed existing physical constants which are supposed to represent your concept of order in the same way you mentioned?...

Comment: @DoubleKnot that is not what the 2nd law of thermodynamics says. It says that *entropy* is maximised, which is different from disorder, as I explained in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/688740/195139) on physics.se.

Comment: @Sandejo yes there's certainly still difference between the technical entropy and the colloquial order, but here the OP's concept of order is clearly not defined in the physical science framework and apparently is defined or insinuated in the sense of something *constant* colloquially but in the meanwhile the 2nd thermodynamic natural law says the critical entropy quantity cannot be constant (increasing) before its final steady-state...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a short list of *physical constants* which are woven into the structure of our universe (the speed of light, the charge on an electron, the strength of gravity, etc.) and as far as we know, these do not change with time or location. Is this what you are asking about?

Comment: for the case of any universe, if those constants were changed even slightly, *we would not be here to notice it* because that universe would not contain the right conditions for life as we know it.

Comment: It seems science reigns supreme here. Since science is generally accepted to be correct, I will accept this answer.

Comment: And then there are the conceived worlds in which the speed of light is not constant. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_speed_of_light  And theories of where the size of electric charge comes from that leave open the possibility it might change. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole#Dirac's_quantization  And searches for changes in various constants. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_large_numbers_hypothesis

Comment: Plus, the OP mentions video games. There are certainly video games in which the physical constants, such as gravity, change in all manner of ways. Asteroids, for example, has zero gravity.

Answer (score 0):

The empirical (physical) component of every possible object is not constant (e.g. atoms are in constant change). What is constant is its representation on the subject, that is, its ideal (metaphysical) representation (notice the counterpoint physical - metaphysical). Even a river can be constant. For more about the structure of matter, check Feynman's [Six Easy Pieces](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0465025277).

But the problem goes farther. A videogame does not exist in nature. In nature, all stuff is just atoms, quarks, fields, whatever --noumena, in ultimate terms--, but not videogames, time, dreams, "Real world", etc. Nothing would exist without a subject that is able to circumscribe a portion of the universe that follows a pattern (according to such subject) and take it as a thing (e.g. a rainbow is a set of atoms/fields/whatever that adjust to a visual pattern), an object (as the counterpart of the subject). In thermodynamics, this dialectical opposition (what is physical and what is metaphysical) is described as *microstates* and *macrostates*. A videogame or a rock would correspond to the macrostatic perception, while the electrons/quarks that flow somewhere correspond to the microstatic behavior.